# Equivalent norms in polynomial space

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, polynomials, lp-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $\mathbb{P}_k(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the space of multivariate polynomials of degree $\le k$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Let $Q=[0,1]^d$ and let $B(0,2)$ be the ball centred at the original with radius 2.

Using the fact that $\mathbb{P}_k(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is a finite dimensional vector space and that polynomials are [real analytic functions](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Real_analytic_function) (hence they admit unique continuation), we know

\begin{equation}
c\|p \|_{L^p(Q)}\le \|p \|_{L^p(B(0,2))}\le C \|p \|_{L^p(Q)}
\end{equation}
for $1\le p \le \infty$, for every $p\in\mathbb{P}_k(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

I'm wondering on which parameters does $C$ depend.

Comment: The parameters are $p, k$, and $d$; the sharp constant depends on all of them, although it's possible to have a uniform bound that only depends on $k$ and $d$. I'm more concerned about the first inequality: why is $\|p \|_{L^p(Q)}\le \|p \|_{L^p(B(0,2))}$? The cube $Q$ contains the point $(1,1,\dots, 1)$ at distance $\sqrt{d}$ from the origin, so it's not contained in $B(0, 2)$ when $d>4$.

Comment: Edited, thank you. Do you know a reference for the sharp constant? @CrazyIvan

Comment: I really need that reference @if....

Comment: I don't have a reference, but here is a bounty.